# How to pass received data from netcat to another script as argument?

Tags: tcp, socket, netcat, nc

I have simple bash `nc` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444 > filename.out
```

which listens `4444` port for `TCP` connection. Instead of redirecting received data to `filename.out` I would like, if possible, to pass each chunk of data (single lines of text) to `script.sh` as argument. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've also tried with:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444 | /path/to/script.sh
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? `nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444 | perl -nle 'print if m/foo/'` prints only input lines containing `foo` for me.

Comment: @thrig good question. `/path/to/script.sh` is bash script that should `echo $1 > result.txt` - fill txt file with `$1` argument which it does not.

Comment: `$1` is the first argument to the script, which is not set in your example. `nc` instead passes the input on standard input, so read it with a `while read line; do ...; done` loop or `cat` or something.

Comment: You also might look at inter-process communication using Bash, one example being at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862970/inter-process-communication-without-fifos . And here is another utilizing  FIFOs http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This below is the entry point to a multi-input script.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"

# your script's payload here
```

The `#!` line is self explanatory I hope

on the second line

`$# -ge 1` and is testing for at least one command line argument

`-a`  is the boolean and operator

`-f "$1"` is testing if the first argument is a file

`&&` is followed by the directive to be executed if the previous condition holds true

`||` is followed by what happens if the test condition is not true

```
nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444 > filename.out
my_processing_script filename.out
```

-or-

```
nc -k -l 127.0.0.1 4444 | my_processing_script
```

so, if I have an argument and it is a file, my input is this file, if not, my input is coming from the pipe, i.e. `"-"`

then you can run your thing as you wish. Either

I tested with payload of

```
awk '{print $2}' ${input}
```

and my input was coming from `netstat -rn` command and worked either way. I hope this is what you are asking about