# netcat / nc / telnet perform math on received data then output

Tags: scripting, netcat, telnet, nc

I am not an expert on bash so sorry in advance. For my high school CTF competition, I have to read in 3 numbers, perform some arithmetic on them, then output the value back to the server.

In pseudocode this is:

```
connect to service
receive 17 bytes
parse 3 nums out of bytes
solution = num1 * num2 / num3
send solution
receive secret_message (if fast enough)
```

However, the second I connect, a timer starts and I then have 0.1 seconds to send the solution.

My first attempt with a python script got me close:

```
import socket
from timeit import default_timer

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("services.cyberprotection.agency", 9999))
t = default_timer()
data = s.recv(17)
print(data)
l = data.split(b"\n")
solution = int(int(l[0]) * int(l[1]) / int(l[2]))
s.sendall(bytes(solution) + b"\n")
t2 = default_timer() - t
print("Too slow by ", round(t2 - 0.1, 4), "seconds")
secret_message = s.recv(128)
print(secret_message)
```

```
$ python3 connect.py
b'66044\n50899\n49665\n'
Too slow by  0.0239 seconds
```

I suspect there would be some way to do this with shell scripting, which would just fast enough for what I need.

**How would I go about piping netcat output to a script, then back to netcat?**

I was not sure how to pipe the output of netcat to another script, then pipe it back to netcat.

```
netcat services.cyberprotection.agency 9999 > out.txt
```

```
netcat services.cyberprotection.agency 9999 | somemagic | somehow_back_to_netcat
```

I have connected using:

- netcat
- nc
- telnet

So any of those tools would work.

This SE link seemed useful, but how do I pipe it back? [How to pass received data from netcat to another script as argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270526/how-to-pass-received-data-from-netcat-to-another-script-as-argument?rq=1)

```bsh
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/services.cyberprotection.agency/9999
start=`date +%s.%N`
out="$(head -3 <&3)"
out2="$out"
array=($out2)
var=$((array[0]*array[1]/array[2]))
echo $var >&3
end=`date +%s.%N`
slowtime=$( echo "$end - $start - 0.1" | bc -l )
echo "$slowtime too slow"
```

Is the answer, but it is still too slow.

Comment: You probably want a [named pipe](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/NamedPipes) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my internet, not the computer that was the limiting factor.

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/services.cyberprotection.agency/9999
out="$(head -3 <&3)"
out2="$out"
array=($out2)
var=$((array[0]*array[1]/array[2]))
echo $var >&3
# Now get secret message
cat <&3
```